# Find data in variable range?

Tags: sql, ms-access

at the first place i tried to make a query in Microsoft office access 2010 to find duplicated data

the query is working just fine but i figured something

this is sample of result

- A      B        VALUE
- ADAM   JOHN      16
- ADAM   JOHN      16

the primary key is to find the duplicated data in ( A , B ,VALUE )
but i found that i need to find also the data nearby the original value if it's exist

i mean i need to make query to find the exact duplicate in ( A , B ) and the values is equal or less than or more than ( VALUE ) if exist , which can be defined by +-5 range for example

ex :

- A      B        VALUE
- ADAM   JOHN      16
- ADAM   JOHN      15

this is what i'm seeking

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT transactions.[A],
 transactions.[B],
 transactions.[Amount],
FROM transactions 
WHERE (((transactions.[A]) In 
   (SELECT [A] 
   FROM [transactions] As Tmp 
   GROUP BY [A],[B] 
   HAVING Count(*)>1 And [B] = [transactions].[B]))) 
ORDER BY transactions.[A], transactions.[B];
```

Comment: Post your SQL so we can see how you're finding your duplicate rows.

Comment: SELECT transactions.[A], transactions.[B],  transactions.[Amount], 
FROM transactions
WHERE (((transactions.[A]) In (SELECT [A] FROM [transactions] As Tmp GROUP BY [A],[B] HAVING Count(*)>1  And [B] = [transactions].[B])))
ORDER BY transactions.[A], transactions.[B];